# How to solve this error?of terminal

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;
int round(double number);
int main()
 {
  double doublevalue;
   char ans;
    do
    {
    cout << "Enter the double value:";
       cin >> doublevalue;
     cout << "Rounded that number is"<<round(doublevalue)<<endl;
     cout << "Again?(y/n)";
     cin >> ans;
      }while(ans=='y' ||ans=='Y');
        cout << "End of testing.\n";
       return 0;
         }
        int round(double number)
      {
      return static_cast<int>(floor(number+0.5));
     }
```

error is as below:

```
 roundoff.cpp:6:24: error: new declaration ‘int round(double)’
  int round(double number);
                    ^
 In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374:0,
             from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/os_defines.h:39,
             from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h:426,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:38,
             from roundoff.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:309:1: error: ambiguates     old declaration ‘double round(double)’
 __MATHCALLX (round,, (_Mdouble_ __x), (__const__));
```

^
           roundoff.cpp: In function ‘int round(double)’:
           roundoff.cpp:22:24: error: new declaration ‘int round(double)’
           int round(double number)
                        ^
      In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374:0,
                   from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits                 /os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits   /c++config.h:426,
                   from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:38,
                 from roundoff.cpp:1:
   /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:309:1: error: ambiguates old declaration ‘double round(double)’
   **MATHCALLX (round,, (*Mdouble* __x), (__const**));
   ^

Comment: please format your code. It's hard to read this way.

Comment: See [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round). To be fair, C++ allows `cmath` to put `round` in the global namespace, so you could get the same error without `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Reverted dupe-hammer abuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the name of your function `round` because `cmath` already defines a method called `round` with same signature causing the ambiguity.  Change the name to `my_round(double number)` instead of `round` and it will work.